# Are there any microformats designed for accessibility purposes?

Tags: html, accessibility, microformats

And are they supported by accessibile browsers (readers)?

I guess the question is pretty simple. Can I signal in my classnames that this is a **search field**, this is a box with **popular tags**, these are the **main navigation** links, this is a box with the **latest comments**, this is a link for your **profile page**, you can **logout** with this link, and so on...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is no. The longer answer is WAI-ARIA can do some of what you want but there's no guarantee that screen readers will support it. For a discussion of WAI-ARIA roles see
http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles
Pay particular attention to section 5.4, things like banner and contentinfo may be useful to you. Do not depend on WAI-ARIA support though; make sure that you use good HTML including descriptive alt tags and headings to separate your document into appropriate sections.

Comment: I would really like the microformats community too access this issue, we know how many years w3.org lags behind the web.

Answer (score 2):

Jared nailed it from a technical point of view. WAI-ARIA is the way forward.

Just wanted to add that there have in fact been some concerns about how microformats impact accessibility. Two posts to read on this:

1. [hAccessibility](http://www.webstandards.org/2007/04/27/haccessibility/)
2. [BBC Withdrawing Some Microformats over Accessibility Concerns](http://accessify.com/news/2008/06/bbc-withdrawing-some-microformats-over-accessibility-concerns/)

I do use microformats as a guideline for building more semantic HTML, but I ignore some of the constructs that I know can cause accessibility problem, specifically the use of `<abbr>`.